# Update extended Meteor.user collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collection2

I have extended by [meteor-collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) user profile

User Profile

```
/// --- User Profile --- ///
UserProfile = new Mongo.Collection("userprofile");
Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    userName: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    userGender: {
        type: String,
        allowedValues: ['Male', 'Female'],
        optional: true
    },
    userAge: {
        type: Number,
        optional: true,
        regEx: /^[0-9]{2}$/
    },
    userWeight: {
        type: Number,
        decimal: true,
        optional: true
    },
    userGrowth: {
        type: Number,
        optional: true
    },
    userExpirience: {
        type: Number,
        optional: true
    },
    userAvatarId: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    profileComplete: {
        type: Boolean,
        optional: true
    }
});
UserProfile.attachSchema(Schema.UserProfile);
```

User

```
/// --- User --- ///
Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-z0-9A-Z_]{3,15}$/
    },
    emails: {
        type: [Object]
    },
    "emails.$.address": {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    },
    "emails.$.verified": {
        type: Boolean
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date
    },
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
        optional: true
    },
    services: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    },
    // Add `roles` to your schema if you use the meteor-roles package.
    // Option 1: Object type
    // If you specify that type as Object, you must also specify the
    // `Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP` group whenever you add a user to a role.
    // Example:
    // Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, ["admin"], Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP);
    // You can't mix and match adding with and without a group since
    // you will fail validation in some cases.
    roles: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    },
    // Option 2: [String] type
    // If you are sure you will never need to use role groups, then
    // you can specify [String] as the type
    roles: {
        type: [String],
        optional: true
    }
});
Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);
```

But I can't update any property of user, for example **useAge**.

When I try to do it:

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: userId}, {$set: {userAge: 30}}, {validate: false});
```

it destroy the data of user and collection contain only **id**

And second question: how I can retrieve data from user profile for ex age?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you overwriting the entire content of the user instead of just the userAge in profile.
I think the small change below will fix your problem:

`Meteor.users.update({_id: userId}, {$set: {profile.userAge: 30}}, {validate: false});`

I'm not sure what you mean by "ex age", the history of the age?

Comment: Hello k.chao. I mean how I can get data from extended users collection. For example get the value of userAge.

Comment: And to reply for second question. To get value of userAge I just should use this: `Meteor.users.findOne({}).profile.userAge`

Comment: The mongoDB findOne operation is actually done asynchronously, so your approach will not work (unless you are doing it on the server). What you need is a callback function:

`Meteor.users.findOne({}, function(err, res) { console.log(res.profile.userAge); })`